# Do Access Database require any database engine?

Tags: c#, database

If we develop application that has access database in it dose it needs to have any other thing installed on client machine with dot net frame work?

Is there any other databse easy to use may be small which does not require additional install than dot net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net). I am using it successfully in several projects.

It requires only .NET Framework 2.0 or higher and one single DLL that is easily XCOPY deployable without any registration/installation.

The performance is somewhat slower than e.g. Microsoft Access (which requires [Jet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine)) but for my purposes it was always good enough.

Another candidate would be [Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (CE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact). This is also a database that requires no installation or registration, you just ship some additional DLLs with your application.

Comment: is that free? is there free one

Comment: IIRC there is/was a community edition of VistaDB. Microsoft SQL CE is free, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what database you are using. If you use MS SQL, you can use the System.Data.SqlClient. If you are using Oracle, you may need to use third party .NET library.

Comment: Oracle brings drivers in their ODP.NET "suite" http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Answer (score 0):

Access will work, you won't need to install any separate software, the .NET framework has data providers for Access, you can use the ODBC provider.

The recommended solution from Microsoft for embedded databases, however, is SQL CE -- check it out, you can embed it in your solution and have your app's installer configure it (no separate installation).  It also has the benefit of being free.

EDIT: As noted below by @Joe, no license is needed to use Access; however, it is a file-based database, and is not as reliable as SQL CE.

Comment: You don't need a licensed copy of MS Access to use an Access/Jet database from .NET.

Comment: From my own experiences I can say that .NET 2.0 does _not_ contain any Jet Access drivers. You would need to install it separately (or hope that the user's Windows/Service Pack level is high enough to include it in the OS). In addition you do not need Microsoft Office Access but just the Jet Redistributables. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114/en

Answer (score 0):

Another is SQLite... a single .dll drop-in and integrates with .Net via simlar

```
using System.Data.SQLite; 

using System.Data.OleDB;  

using System.Data.SQL;

using System.Data.ODBC;
```

each have similar signatures for creating connections, creating SQLCommand objects, Parameterizations, execution, etc...  When I was doing testing between different platforms, I found SQLite database and Visual Foxpro database faster than Access.  When compared to VistaDB (just simulating populating large dataset of 100k records), it almost choked on me.